# How to write "if grep a and grep b" structure in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I write "`if grep a and grep b`" structure

```
if [ grep -q Bug test.txt  ] && [ grep -q Ver test.txt ]
then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

But the result is wrong, what is the true grammar of the code?

The wrong result:

```
./test.sh: line 2: [: too many arguments
not found
```

Answer (score 8):

The condition in a shell `if` is a command, so

```
 if grep -q Bug test.txt && grep -q Ver test.txt; then
   echo "found"
 else
   echo "not found"
 fi
```

This holds true even for `if [ foo -eq bar ]`; `[` is a command (an alias for `test`) that returns `0` (which is by convention true in the shell) if the condition it is asked to evaluate is true. `grep` returns `0` if it finds a match and a non-zero value (by convention false in the shell) otherwise, so `if grep -q foo bar` is fine.